# VB Code to Select All Sheets except the First Two

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, select

I am creating a report where I need to run a macro that will select all worksheets except the first two ("Intro" and "Contents").  The names of the first two sheets are constant, but the data sheets will change over time, which is why I don't want to hard code each one.  I will be building multiple macros off this base one to send all sheets to the printer, save as a PDF, run validation, etc.  Just need help with the base structure to get them all selected.  Thanks!

Comment: Size an array to [number of sheets -2] then loop over the sheets, skipping Intro and Contents - add the others to the array. Then you can use something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yourArrayHere).Select`

Comment: Another option: Resize the array on the fly. (probably slower, but for a handfull of sheets should be ok).  ```Dim wsNames() As String  ReDim wsNames(0)

Start your loop here
ReDim Preserve wsNames(UBound(wsNames) + 1)
wsNames(UBound(wsNames)) = "YourSheetName"
End loop

Sheets(wsNames).Select```